# Qual è il senso di "arruffato" in questo passaggio?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel racconto *L'isola*, di Giani Stuparich, ho letto:

> Ricordava l'orto a cui si scendeva per alcuni gradini, misero orto **arruffato**, con in mezzo un fico e sul muro, unica bellezza, un grande cappero.

Ho cercato il termine "arruffare" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire il senso dell'espressione "orto arruffato" che appare in questo brano. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In questo blog che parla di orti nell'articolo *[Tutto Quello che Dovresti Sapere per Avere un Orto Sinergico](https://www.houzz.it/magazine/tutto-quello-che-dovresti-sapere-per-avere-un-orto-sinergico-stsetivw-vs%7E66865341)* si può leggere:

> L’orto sinergico potrà risultare a volte ***arruffato***, un po’ imperfetto,
> i cavoli potranno avere una foglia o due bucherellate, ma tutto questo
> aumenta la biodiversità dell’orto e la sua genuinità.

Da Treccani per *arruffato*, tratto dalla definizione di [arruffare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/arruffare/):

> Part. pass. arruffato, anche come agg., disordinato, scomposto

Il significato nel contesto da te citato sembra quindi che l'orto risultasse disordinato, imperfetto oltre che misero come già descritto dall'autore.